# Total Commander, is Move supposed to work over FTP?

Tags: file-transfer, file-management, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I'm using an AT&T Note 4 with Total Commander (the latest according to Google Play) and sending files to FileZilla server 0.9.41 on Windows.  The user has read, write, delete, and append for files, and create directory permissions

The move command on Total Commander does not seem to work.  It's copying the files, but not deleting them from the Note 4 after the copy.  I can manually delete the files.  Occasionally I get an error about permissions where it says it can't delete the folder.

I was trying to move things from Downloads, and now I am moving other things.

It took me a while to figure out how to move things with Total Commander (it's backwards), so I wonder if my expectations are also misplaced.  Should a move command to an FTP server work like a regular move command anywhere else?

**EDIT**

It seems like there are special permissions for Android installed/default directories.  I'm so used to root access that I forget this phone isn't rooted.  Directories and files within those behaved as I expected.

Comment: Why not try a different file manager app? Alternatively, you can install busybox and use a set of simple commands (such as `wget` and `rm`) to do the job as well.